# Set attribut value using JS, clears after every value set Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given :

```
                    for i in list('{}'.format(value)):
                        self.browser.execute_script(
                            "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{}');".format(i.replace('\n', '')),
                            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("{}".format(xpath)))
```

Lets say the given string to be typed is "asd"
It types 'a' then, it removes it and types 's', then removes 's' and types 'd' and removes when another action is performed (type to another field or a click on another element)

Example HTML element :

```
<input type="text" class="validate-input input-error" placeholder="Introdu TOKEN" value="">
```

PS. Same clear is done even if the for loop is not used and the value is directly passed to the js script.

EDIT: It is mandatory that the element selector is by xpath.

Comment: can you share more details about what you are trying to do? if you want to set a value with xpath you can just use the sendKeys method

Comment: I want an alternative to sendKeys, using javascript, it's more robust, sendkeys is not constant for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one tested solution for setting the value with XPath in JS 
PS: I'm using webdriver_manager to manage browsers

```
def setValueByXpath(xpahtValue, inputValue):
    string = "document.evaluate('" + xpahtValue + "', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value = '" + inputValue + "'"
    driver.execute_script(string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')

// call the above method with desierd xpath and value for it
    setValueByXpath('//*[@name="q"]', 'Paint Drying')

//I'm doing a search by pressing the enter button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="q"]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: This does work, but the website seems to not detect any typing is done, and therefore dosen;t enable Login button for example, while in ur case its not required. But this is what I was looking for basically, welldone